# Selenium Web Driver Click

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I am having issues with these last lines working. The last search button part is where it breaks. It says"unknown error:cannot focus element".the last lines are simply just clicking the search button.

Here is the html code im getting it from. This is the search button code.

```
 <img class="Banner-Search-Type-search-ImageStyle" 
 src="images/BannerImages/go-img.png" id="btnsearch">
```

Here is my code.

```
 var mfgPartNumber = "CRCW12061R00FKEA";
        IWebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\josimpso\AppData\Roaming");
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://app.siliconexpert.com/CMOMFX/customerlogin.html");
        //Set Username
        IWebElement setUserName = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("logininput"));
        setUserName.SendKeys("userName");
        //Set Password
        IWebElement setPassword = driver.FindElement(By.Name("password"));
        setPassword.SendKeys("Password");
        // Click login button
        IWebElement loginButton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginsubmit"));
        loginButton.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);

        // Now search based on mfgPartNumber
        IWebElement searchBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtsearch"));
        searchBox.SendKeys(mfgPartNumber);
        // Press enter on the search
        IWebElement searchButton = driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnsearch"));
        searchButton.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
```

Comment: Also, How do i make the send key right click the button? Not click enter. Clicking enter won't make it search the go button.

Comment: why aren't you just getting the button By.Id like you did with the txtsearch textbox?

Comment: That didn't work either. I just tried this one. I'll switch it to Id. Id doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm unable to test it right now, but your image should be inside a `<a>` tag. You perform the click in the `<a>` tag, not in the image

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of the SendKeys, which is not been sent successfully.

Instead of SendKeys, try using ActionClass,which is another way of sending keys.

For e.g,

```
Actions new_action = new Actions(driver);
```

`new_action.sendKeys("VALUE");`